# Unable to find executable for

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, executable

I am new to programming and I can't seem to figure out how to get my debugger in Visual Studio Code to work. I am trying to use the Swift extension, which I installed, and try to make an app. However, when I run my code, I get the error: "Unable to find executable for 'C:...\Swift<executable file>.exe'

Can someone help me fix this and begin to code?

I have checked and the CodeLLDB is also installed and globally enabled.